# How can I make the dots in a ToC end at the same place?

Tags: table-of-contents

In my table of contents, some of the dot fills do not end at the same place as the other lines. What is causing this and how can I make the dot fills uniform? A red oval highlights the problem in the following screenshot:

[image: Extra dot in ToC]

*Edit:* It looks as if the page number "101" is slightly less wide than the other page numbers, allowing just enough room for an extra dot. This is probably the cause, but I still don't know how to fix the problem.

*Edit 2:* Minimal working example below. The document class is located at https://github.com/wannesm/adsphd/blob/master/adsphd.cls, and is quite long -- apologies for the inconvenience.

```
\documentclass{adsphd}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter % Arabic page numbering

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{98}
\chapter{Numerical solution of bivariate and polyanalytic polynomial systems}
\section{Introduction}\clearpage
\section{Notation and preliminaries}\clearpage
\section{Solving systems of bivariate and polyanalytic polynomials}\clearpage
\subsection{The polynomial eigenvalue problem}\clearpage
\subsection{Balancing the system and its associated pencil}\clearpage
\subsubsection{Balancing the bivariate system}\clearpage
\subsubsection{Balancing the polyanalytic system}\clearpage
\subsubsection{Balancing the pencil}\clearpage
\section{Numerical experiments}\clearpage
\section{Conclusion}\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a problem with `microtype`. Use

```
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\tableofcontents
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
```

for the Table of Contents.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If one removes `\usepackage{microtype}` from that class file, the error vanishes also! Perhaps, one should notify the maintainer/creator of the class file about this 'feature'?

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Is this a bug in microtype that will be fixed soon?

Comment: It is mentioned in the `microtype` documentation in the "Hints and caveats" chapter as one of the places where you might want to disable protrusion. I'm not sure it can be seen as a bug in `microtype` as such. Rather I think that classes that use it ought to redefine  `\tableofcontents` like this.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've notified the maintainer of the class, should be fixed soon - thanks!