# Troubles customizing the ToC with tocloft

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft, books, book-design

I'm having difficulties in setting up the ToC of a large book with many chapters, sections and subsections.  The horizontal spacings aren't right, and the dots to the page number isn't right neither.  Here's a MWE showing the troubles:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
    \renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{2}  %  Points spacement.
    \makeatletter  % To fix a small offset with page number.  TO BE FIXED!
    \renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.3em} % {1.75em}  TO BE FIXED!

    % Chapter spacement:
    \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\ }
    \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\newline}
    \setlength{\cftchapindent}{0pt} % Spacement to left of chapter number.
    \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt} %

    % Sections spacement:
    \renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\hfill} % ??
    \renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{~} % Appears to be too short.  TO BE FIXED!
    \setlength{\cftsecindent}{11pt} % Random number?  TO BE FIXED!
    \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{32pt} % Random number?  TO BE FIXED!
    \addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{8pt} % ??

    % Sub-sections spacement:
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\hfill} % ??
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{~} % Appears to be too short.  TO BE FIXED!
    \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{56pt} % Random number?  TO BE FIXED!
    \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{48pt} % Random number?  TO BE FIXED!
    \addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{12pt} %  ??

\begin{document}

\frontmatter 

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\setcounter{page}{12}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\setcounter{page}{850}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{section}{12}
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{subsection}{15}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]

\setcounter{chapter}{12}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\setcounter{page}{1311}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{subsection}{14}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{section}{15}
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{subsection}{12}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]

\backmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Preview, with troubles shown in red:

[image]

1. As the picture shows, there are some extra dots on the right side.  How to fix this?  I need a constant spacing between the last dot and its page number, or all the dots should be aligned (whatever the page number).
2. The spacing looks a bit too tight between the section/subsection title and its number.  What should I use instead of `{~}` ?
3. The spacings to the left margin appear to be random and I don't know what numbers I should use there, for a book that uses 11 points fonts.  Currently, I used funny looking numbers by eyes only (11pt, 32pt, 8pt, 56pt, 48pt, 12pt ??).  I need help there.

---

**EDIT:**  About the dots problem, the `microtype` package appears to be the cause of the extra dots.  A simple solution is given there:  [How can I make the dots in a ToC end at the same place?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172785/how-can-i-make-the-dots-in-a-toc-end-at-the-same-place)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a revised version of your MWE.

```
% tocprob.tex  SE 557386

\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
    \renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{2.10}  %  Points spacement. % PW changed
    \makeatletter  % To fix a small offset with page number.  TO BE FIXED!
    \renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.3em} % {1.75em}  TO BE FIXED!

    % Chapter spacement:
    \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\ }
    \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\newline}
    \setlength{\cftchapindent}{0pt} % Spacement to left of chapter number.
    \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt} %

    % Sections spacement:
%    \renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\hfill} % ??
%    \renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{~} % Appears to be too short.  TO BE FIXED!
%    \setlength{\cftsecindent}{11pt} % Random number?  TO BE FIXED!
%    \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{32pt} % Random number?  TO BE FIXED!
    \addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{8pt} % ??

    % Sub-sections spacement:
%    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\hfill} % ??
%    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{~} % Appears to be too short.  TO BE FIXED!
%    \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{56pt} % Random number?  TO BE FIXED!
%    \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{48pt} % Random number?  TO BE FIXED!
    \addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{12pt} %  ??

\begin{document}

\frontmatter 

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\setcounter{page}{12}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\setcounter{page}{850}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{section}{12}
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{subsection}{15}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]

\setcounter{chapter}{12}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\setcounter{page}{1311}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{subsection}{14}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{section}{15}
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-4]
\setcounter{subsection}{12}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2-4]

\backmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Basically what I have done is to comment out many of your `tocloft` changes to revert back to the general ToC layout. In some places you needed extra space between numbers and titles and I just added the extra space to the default spacing. I don't know what caused the problem with the dot spacing but changing your `\cftdotsep` from `2` to `2.10` seems to have fixed that.

Comment: About the dots, the microtype package appears to be the culprit. Solution there :  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172785/how-can-i-make-the-dots-in-a-toc-end-at-the-same-place